# ReactJS Can't get e.target.value of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### Expected

e.target.value returns me the value of the input in the form I submitted

#### Results

e contains a strange React changed object, [SyntheticEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)?

```
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={ onSubmitName }>
            <input id="name_field"
                   title="Name:"
                   placeholder={ user.name }/>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

^ Above is my form, below is the onSubmit which is inside of a Redux mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmitName: (e) => {
            console.log('e', e);
            e.preventDefault();
            const name = document.getElementById('name_field').value;
            dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_NAME", payload: handleOnSubmit(name) })
        }
    }
}
```

e.preventDefault no longer exists on the new converted `event`.[image]

How is this now handled in React? The documentation provides no work arounds. To get `e.preventDefault()` to work again and `e.target.value`

#### Full code

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name_field').value;
    return name;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmitName: (e) => {
            console.log('e', e);
            e.preventDefault();
            const name = document.getElementById('name_field').value;
            dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_NAME", payload: handleOnSubmit(name) })
        }
    }
}

const NameField = ({ user, onSubmitName }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ onSubmitName }>
                <input id="name_field"
                       title="Name:"
                       placeholder={ user.name }/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

const NameContainer = connect(
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NameField);

export default NameContainer;
```

Comment: Why aren't you mapping` stateToProps`?

Comment: @Umair makes a good point. the first argument to connect is mapping state, if you don't need access to state there the first argument should be null

Comment: `var name` seems to be a string when you pass it into `handleOnSubmit()` in `dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_NAME", payload: handleOnSubmit(name) })`,

so the `const handleOnSubmit` function is accepting a string (not a SyntheticEvent), which does not have a `preventDefault()` method available

Comment: Yes. Also, you are missing `value` prop on input field.

Comment: @Umair when I add a value prop, it turns the form into a read-only field, however seems I can get around that with an onChange function, but I don't need that right now.

Comment: value prop is not needed to fix your error. preventDefault should definitely be a function. can you try passing null as your first argument to connect? or perhaps even inlining `e.preventDefault` inside your submit function? `onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}` to make sure that works?

Comment: `e.preventDefault` is still not a function, the e looks the same as the `console.log` screenshot above. There must be some strange react thing I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I see in your code is that you're passing `name` to `handleOnSubmit` then trying to `preventDefault` on it which will fail because `name` is a string (the input value) not the event. You don't need to `preventDefault` twice.

```
const name = document.getElementById('name_field').value
dispatch({ 
  type: "CHANGE_NAME", 
  payload: handleOnSubmit(name) // name is a string
})
```

which calls:

```
const handleOnSubmit = (e) => { // e is name, not event.
  e.preventDefault(); // crashes 
  ..
  ..
}
```

I think you can just remove the outside function, handle preventing the default behaviour in your mapped dispatch call.

In the end your code should look like:

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSubmitName: e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const name = document.getElementById('name_field').value
      dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_NAME", payload: name })
    }
  }
}

const NameField = ({ user, onSubmitName }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitName}>
        <input 
          id="name_field"
          title="Name:"
          placeholder={user.name}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

const NameContainer = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(NameField)

export default NameContainer
```

can check the [webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KlUO4XsCzlXGkriT6_m) i made

Comment: Thanks! I still have no idea how that e.preventDefault works. The e object on inspection does not contain that method.

Comment: console.log only logs ownProperties so the native preventDefault won't show up, but it will be called when climbing up the prototype chain

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `value` prop on `input` element. Also, you need to passing in `null` as the first argument to `connect`

```
const NameField = ({ user, onSubmitName }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ onSubmitName }>
                <input id="name_field"
                       title="Name:"
                       placeholder={ user.name }
                       value={ user.name }
                 />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In your `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmitName: (e) => {
            // use e.target.value
        }
    }
}
```